# Drupal 7: How may I customize the user profile? And how do I add to it profile2 fields?

Tags: templates, drupal, profile, field

The profile under user/n will only show the profile picture and the username.

I´m using an Omega subtheme.
I´ve copied and pasted the default user-profile.tpl.php file, deleted everything and  added these two lines, hoping that one of them would work:

```
print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['main'], 'field_nombrecompleto1'));
print $field_profile_nombre_completo['value'];
```

The second line refers to the original core profile field, and the first one refers to the imported field (I´ve imported using the migrate module in D6, before I´ve upgraded to D7).

None of the fields gets printed out.
I´ve added this at the top of the template:

```
print "<pre>";  
$vars = get_defined_vars();
print_r($vars);  
print "</pre>";
```

And nothing happend. So I´ve added that code to the top of my page.tpl file, and it appeared the whole list of variables.
At the very top it prints:

```
[template_file] => sites/all/themes/liga/templates/page.tpl.php
```

And at some points it actually recognizes the (core profile) field:

```
    [content] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => Array
                                        (
                                            [system_main] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [field_profile_nombre_completo] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [#theme] => field
                                                            [#weight] => 0
                                                            [#title] => Apellido y Nombres
                                                            [#access] => 1
                                                            [#label_display] => hidden
                                                            [#view_mode] => full
                                                            [#language] => und
                                                            [#field_name] => field_profile_nombre_completo
                                                            [#field_type] => text
...
```

I´ve then deleted everything at my user-profile template and printed just XXXXXX and it didn´t printed out. It stills print the profile image and the username.

**Now I have two issues here:
How to customize the profile template (user-profile.tpl.php) because it´s not recognizing the file inside my theme folder, and how to print profile2 fields information inside the user profile.**

Hope anyone can give me some insight or clue.
THANKS!!!

Rosamunda

Comment: -1 without any explanation?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple sites. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56623/drupal-7-how-may-i-customize-the-user-profile-and-how-do-i-add-to-it-profile2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default the profile2 fields are rendered on a separate tabbed page on the user profile page.
You should be able to get the users profile fields with the function [profile2_by_uid_load($uid, $type_name)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!contrib!profile2_page.module/function/profile2_by_uid_load/7)